# Exterior LED floods worked for a week

Tags: electrical, led, exterior

Bought 4 new Philips 120-Watt Equivalent PAR38 floodlight bulbs and installed in double flood light fixtures at corners of house. Worked great for a week...
Now when I flip the on switch, none of the four LED bulbs turn on. IF, I replace one of the LED bulbs with ANY sort of incandescent bulb, the other three LEDs begin illuminating. Any ideas as to the cause of the problem?

P.S. Just a plain old flip switch! The other thing that adds to the puzzle is that I installed four additional LED floodlights on the front corners of house and those are working OK. Only difference is front lights are on a three-way switch. Keep in mind that the problem lights worked fine for a week

Comment: Is there any kind of smart switch, motion sensor, dimmer, lighted switch, anything like that involved?

Comment: Or electronic timer or photocell?